Termwise Differentiation of Convergent Series Involving the Riemann Zeta Function
Let $\zeta(s)$ be the Riemann zeta function. We know that
$$\zeta(s) = \prod_p(1 - p^{-s})^{-1}, \ \operatorname{Re} s > 1$$
in the sense that the righthand side converges absolutely to $\zeta(s)$ on $\operatorname{Re} s > 1$ and uniformly on $\operatorname{Re} s > 1 + \delta$ for any $\delta > 0$. As a result, using the definition of convergence of an infinite product and the fact that log is continuous, we have
$$\log \zeta(s) = \sum_p -\log(1 - p^{-s})$$
on $\operatorname{Re} s > 1$ in the sense that the righthand side converges to the lefthand side absolutely, and where logs are principal-valued. Using the Taylor expansion for $-\log(1 - z)$ when $|z| < 1$, we have
$$\log \zeta(s) = \sum_p \sum_m \frac{p^{-ms}}{m}$$
valid for $\operatorname{Re} s > 1$. Why may I termwise differentiate to produce
$$-\frac{\zeta'(s)}{\zeta(s)} = -\sum_p \sum_m (\log p)p^{-ms}?$$
I only know that we are allowed to termwise differentiate convergent power series and convergent Dirichlet series, and this does not appear to be either.

What do you mean by $\log \zeta(s)$ when ${\rm Re}(s)>1$ if that first equation is not just a definition of the left side?

I have amended my post, and am willing to a) be wrong there or b) amend it further for additional clarification.

You say “log is continuous” but that is meaningless: there is no continuous homomorphism from $\mathbf C^\times  \to \mathbf C$ that is inverse to the exponential, so you can’t just say “log of a product is the sum of the logs” for analytic functions without  giving an actual definition of what you even mean by $\log \zeta(s)$.

A logarithm of an analytic nonvanishing function $f$ on a connected open set $U$ in the plane is an analytic function $g$ on $U$ such that $f=e^g$ on $U$ and $g$ is provably unique up to adding an integer multiple of $2\pi i$.  Show your double sum exponentiates to $\zeta(s)$ on ${\rm Re}(s)>1$, so it is a logarithm of $\zeta(s)$ by the definition I gave, and making it be real-valued when $s>1$ (the usual log on positive real numbers) uniquely specifies this choice among all analytic logarithms of the zeta-function on that right half-plane.

Thank you, Keith! I am happy to have been corrected on this issue. It makes things much easier!

The right side is an absolutely convergent double series: it can be rearranged to a Dirichlet series that is absolutely convergent on ${\rm Re}(s)>1$, so it can be rearranged at will and differentiated termwise with the derivative being absolutely convergent there too.
